# How to get a prompt for information using a batch file?

Tags: batch-file, scripting, automation

I currently have a .bat file named `RunRDA.bat` which contains:

```
@echo off
rda -v %1 -i "C:\me\rda-tools-1.7.0.Ra1\Input" -o "C:\me\rda-tools-1.7.0.RC1\Output"
```

Which I can run by navigating to the following folder for example:

```
C:\RDA>
```

and entering a command like

```
C:\RDA>RunRDA 848
```

so the batch file takes the input number and runs the command.

As you can see this requires a step of navigating to the specific folder `c:\RDA` before running the .bat file. I was wondering if there is a way I could double click to open the .bat file so that when CMD opens all i need to do is enter the input number and hit enter, without having to navigate to the mentioned directory, therefore eliminating the navigation step.

Comment: Thank you for the formatting fixes @JosefZ & sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I can understand your target, next code snippet could lead to a solution:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "param=%1"
if not defined param set /P "param=Please enter the input number: "
if not defined param goto :doNothing

pushd C:\RDA
rda -v %param% -i "C:\me\rda-tools-1.7.0.Ra1\Input" -o "C:\me\rda-tools-1.7.0.RC1\Output"
echo done with %param%
popd
goto :doNext

:doNothing
echo no input number defined!

:doNext
pause
```

**Resources** (required reading):

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- [Windows CMD Shell Command Line Syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html)

Answer (score 0):

This opens a console window and prompts the user to enter the number before continuing with rda:

```
@echo off
set /p rda_param=Enter rda parameter:
rda -v %rda_param% -i "C:\me\rda-tools-1.7.0.Ra1\Input" -o "C:\me\rda-tools-1.7.0.RC1\Output"
```